# hidden/invisible ref?

Tags: ref

I am writing a textbook which I want to be consistent.
Sometimes I do not refer to a statement explicitly, but I want to add an invisible reference, so if latter I will decide to delete the corresponding statement I will see a LaTeX error.

Is there a simple or/and standard way to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you could use

```
 \newcommand\hiddenref[1]{\sbox0{\ref{#1}}}
```

which makes `\hiddenref{xx}` typeset the reference into a box that is then not used.